# Application of Markov Inequality(and/or Chebyshev's Inequality) to prove multivariable case

Tags: probability, expected-value, variance, covariance

I'm trying to solve a problem that I think uses Markov Inequality(or chebyshev). But not sure how to apply it. the problem is like this:

> Show that
>   $$P(|X-E(X)|+|Y-E(Y)|\geq4\sigma)\leq\frac{1}{2}.$$
>   (the random variables X, Y have common variance $\sigma^2$)

I am assuming this is somehow extension of univariate case into multivariate, but I am not sure how to approach this question. I did prove the case where $P(|(X-E(X))+(Y-E(Y))|)\leq\frac{1+\rho}{2}$ But not sure about this case. Thank you.

Comment: If you state the Markov's inequality precisely you will be able to see that your problem is incorrectly stated.

Comment: oh I am sorry, I see what I did wrong there.. just fixed the problem... sorry for confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A=X-E(X)$ and $B=Y-E(Y)$. Then note that
$$  |A| + |B| \ge 4\sigma   \implies |A|>2\sigma \text{ or } |B|>2\sigma.$$
The same thing written with set notation:
$$ \{ |A| + |B| \ge 4\sigma  \} \subset \{ |A|>2\sigma\} \cup \{ |B|>2\sigma \}.$$
Applying monotonicity of $P$, [union bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boole%27s_inequality), and then [Chebyshev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev's_inequality) gives
$$ P(|A| + |B| \ge 4\sigma ) \le P(|A| \ge 2\sigma) + P(|B|\ge 2\sigma) \le\frac1{2^2} + \frac1{2^2} = \frac12. $$